# Magento 2 going down for no reason

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a server with Magento 2 installed and the website goes down randomly for no reason whatsoever. When it goes down I restart the server and the website comes back up. I'm running the top command and there is no indication either on the resources being consumed while the website goes down

It is an instance on AWS with 8 core and 32 GB of ram using Provisioned IOPS SSD storage.

I'm completely dumbfounded by this. Already cleared all logs for Magento and database logs to clear up space because I was running low on space

Comment: have you checked that disk space usage when magento goes down? any clue from log files? sometimes there out of memory errors that are not well highlited... what happens if you run some magento commands , like setup:upgrade or setup:static-content:deploy? any error?

Comment: and, is it just magento that does not work in that case or all the server goes down? what deploy mode are you running? try also disabling cache and see what happens

Comment: We have staging copy of the live site on the same server and when the live site goes down the staging site works fine so this has to be a Magento issue.

Comment: Yes we have checked the logs, and no errors. Seems like something is consuming all of the memory when this happens

Comment: so you have both sites on the same server.... could it be an issue of some misconfigured configuration on the resources of the server?? the allocated php size or something like that?

Comment: I have more information now. It is related to running the recommended cron jobs for Magento and one of the jobs is making the website unresponsive http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html
Still investigating which part it causing the issue

Comment: Do you have any of the cron logs with any info about their misconfiguration?